# Apple Push Notification : Can we remove some text from notification message before it has to be displayed to user on iphone

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I'm using *Apple push notification service* and its working fine.
But I want to remove some text from message before it has to be displayed on device.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: reffer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41345889/its-possible-to-change-push-notification-message-before-display-on-device-from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The payload data which we send to APNS server is going to display on device. If you have to remove some text then it must have to remove before sending to APNS server. You can not manage notification text message.