# It's possible to change push notification message before display on device from iOS side?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Display my push notification message is "Message from: +919687335565"

attached screenshot : 
[image]

I just want to fetch the name of this +919687335565 contact number from the `Address book` and **display name of this contact** instead of a phone number in `push notification`.

Before displaying `notification` i want to replace **phone number +919687335565** with its **contact name Chandresh** in push notification.

like attached screenshot : 
[image]

Comment: Whatever is sent in the payload of the push notification is displayed in the banner shown to the user. If you want to customize this message, you'll have to change what you are sending to the APNs service.

Comment: let me check !!! VoIP

Comment: @ChandreshKachariya check my answer.

Comment: I think you need to sync your contacts with server on each app launch and set aps content with name instead number.

Comment: @SatishVekariya Don't required to sync contacts with server and also already answer is given in belove by dirtydanee. Without sync it's possible using Silent Notifications.

Comment: @ChandreshKachariya No, It not possible with silent push.
Once your app is terminated from app switcher, I guarantee!!

Comment: @SatishVekariya silent push is working in my application in every state. It's one type VOIP service so work after terminated app

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are various possibilities for preprocessing and modify the payload of a notification on iOS.

**Before iOS 10**

You could be sending [Silent Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1), what will not be not shown to the user. Will wake our application when it is terminated or in background, and you will be able to do preprocessing on the notification content. See more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694963/what-is-silent-push-notification-when-does-the-device-receive-it), how to set it up. However, this notification type is not 100% reliable, and should not be abused, e.g. used for all notifications to be delivered, because Apple could stop the notifications to be sent after a number of messages.

The other option is, if your application supports `VoIP`. This way your app will pretty much always listen to push notifications, and you will be always available to preprocess the notifications, before you would be displaying them. However, if your app does not have real `VoIP` capabilities, e.g. phone calls, your app will be rejected by Apple on the review. [Here](http://pierremarcairoldi.com/ios-8-voip-notifications/) is a great tutorial, how to set it up.

**From iOS 10**

With the introduction of iOS 10, we are finally able to do preprocessing on our notifications, even, when the app is in background or terminated. No `VoIP` capabilities or special type of notifications needed to be sent. [Here](https://blog.pusher.com/how-to-send-ios-10-notifications-using-the-push-notifications-api/) is a great tutorial, how to set it up.

Comment: You can't wake a force-killed (terminated) app with a silent notification, can you ?

Answer (score -1):

This is possible, except:

> want to fetch name of this +91********* contact number from Address book

because `Address Book` is not accessible when app is in background!
You have to write separate logic in app itself to replace mobile no by appropriate name.

How other than this is possible:

**Before iOS 10 and iOS 8+:**
Use **PushKit** to send silent push notifications, app will be woken up by iOS, change the mobile no by name, show local notification.

**iOS 10+:**
Use **Notification Service Extension** to alter notification content before it'll shown to user.
[Look at this official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension)

Using this service extension, iOS gives you a way to first receive notification directly to app, modify content and then deliver to user.
Here you can change mobile no by name.

Comment: It's possible to fetch contact number from address book while app is in background.!!! In my case.

Comment: The AddressBook/Contacts API is also not accessible from a service extension. There is no way for the user to grant permission to access it.

Answer (score -3):

No this is not possible.
Because the push notification is handle by server.
This message is only change by server not from app because that time 
app is in background or terminated.
But you can change message when app is in foreground and background fetch is 
enable then you can customize your message and can show it.

Comment: Thanks @vivek padaya for your valuable response but i required when apps is terminated also in background, because it's client requirement.

Comment: But it is not possible in iOS but You can achieve it in android.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32760520/voip-app-ios8-is-pushkit-still-best-practice

Comment: here we are talking about normal push not VoIP push

Comment: i strongly believe this answer is highly inaccurate, and very miss-leading.

Comment: This is not true, there are ways to achieve this!