# Modify the Push notification content from Userinfo in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, unusernotificationcenter

When receiving a notification, I want to change the user info content before showing in mobile notification in iOS.

```
"aps": {
    "alert": {
        "body": "hello",
        "sound": "Default"
        "badge": "1"

    }
}
```

Example I want to show *world* instead of *hello*.

Is this possible in iOS 10?

Comment: Please refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41345889/its-possible-to-change-push-notification-message-before-display-on-device-from

Answer (score 2):

You can implement notification extension for it. Here is link : [Notification Extension](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjjrbnx7YzUAhXJN48KHQpVCzkQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Freference%2Fusernotifications%2Funnotificationserviceextension&usg=AFQjCNH-5zT7xYHsXv-GjYSzQTc4YpUQ3Q)

You must implement the didReceive(_:withContentHandler:) method and use it to process incoming notifications.

```
override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
  self.contentHandler = contentHandler
  bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

  if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
    // Modify the notification content here
    // Convert received string
    let data = bestAttemptContent.body.data(using: .utf8)!
    // Apply encoded string
    bestAttemptContent.body = String(data: data, encoding: .utf16)

    contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
   }
}
```

Comment: objective  c if possible

Comment: Please have a look on - https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension/1648229-didreceivenotificationrequest?language=objc

Comment: I found this -(void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request
withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent *contentToDeliver))contentHandler;
 if you don't mind can you help me out on this ...to same how to change in objective c for  aps  notification .

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-10-creating-custom-notification-interfaces--cms-27251  will  generate for **local-notification**  ??