# Ios Voip Apns Push Notification Delay by 4 minutes

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, erlang, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I am using AMAZON SNS but facing a delay in push notification reception by 4 minutes, can you help me with this ?

Another Query would that if it is possible can you provide me with the guidelines for my Objective-C front-end developers, if in case it happens to be there fault in any case ?

Comment: Reference this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41345889/its-possible-to-change-push-notification-message-before-display-on-device-from

Comment: Could you add more detail on what you're doing and with which library, language, etc? Add part of your code as well, if you can.

Comment: Are you using AWS SDK for iOS - SNS? https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/tree/master/AWSSNS

Answer (score 0):

As per the AWS documentation [here](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/), there is possible delay if the message delivery is failed in the initial attempts

*Mobile push: If the mobile endpoint is not available, SNS will retry 2 times immediately, 5 times at 20 seconds apart, then 31 times exponentially backing off from 20 seconds to 20 minutes and finally 12 times every 20 minutes for a total 50 attempts over more than 4 hours before the message is discarded from SNS.*