# How to set persistent push notification programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, apn

We are using interactive push notifications in my application, but it will disappear automatically, is there any way to change this push notification banner settings to persistent banner programmatically.
[please check the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWCIN.jpg)

Comment: When you write "We are using...", people expect the question to have at least one line of code. An illustration of "what" is disappearing would be nice as well (maybe a screenshot).

Comment: Check It: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41345889/its-possible-to-change-push-notification-message-before-display-on-device-from

Comment: Seems like a good way to encourage your users to switch off notifications for your app.