# Error in Silent notification display banner in Objective c iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, silent-notification

I am implementing Silent notification in Objective c Code in ios 11. Using FCM Notification by adding this method. 
[What is Silent Push Notification? When does the device receive it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694963/what-is-silent-push-notification-when-does-the-device-receive-it)

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
{

   //Success
    handler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

and paylod is :

```
    {
    "aps" = {
        "content-available" : 1,
        "sound" : ""
    };
    // You can add custom key-value pair here...
}
```

`didReceiveRemoteNotification` method call when notification recived But my question is why banner is visible when silent notification receive. How to restrict notification banner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is difference between remote notification and silent notification in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275060/what-is-difference-between-remote-notification-and-silent-notification-in-ios)

Comment: can you try removing `"sound" : ""` from your payload?

Comment: Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41345889/its-possible-to-change-push-notification-message-before-display-on-device-from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove extra keys from aps array and payload should be like this.

```
"aps" = {
    "content-available" : 1
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I R&D on it. finally i got link form youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xde7ns5w9LM . i remove extra keys from payload like alert title etc just add following and issue resolve.

```
"aps" = {
    "content-available" : 1,
    "sound" : ""
};
```